# Bash: Deny rename access for a directory

Tags: bash, file-permissions

I have used `chmod 0000` on a directory yet the directory can still be renamed. How can I prevent a user from modifying the name of a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing write permission on the parent directory should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you own a file (or directory) you can still perform various operations on it regardless of permissions including `mv`, `rm` and `chmod`.  Other users cannot perform these options based on write permissions.  If you want to prevent the *owner* from moving the directory, you can't.  The owner can always use `chmod` on the file.  The only solution would be to change the owner of the file or move the file under a write-protected directory that the user does not own.